# How to tune the touchpad?

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, multi-touch, gestures

My machine is lenovo yoga s730 on Ubuntu 20.04. I have several problems with my touchpad. Firstly, it's active while typing. Even though there is 'disable while typing' option in the settings, it does not work. I've tried to implement this via some tweaks and stuff, but it didn't work out for me. Perhaps, I did something wrong, I'm new to Linux. The second problem - gestures. My touchpad has multitouch and in Windows I could tune gestures, but I cannot now. Again, used some gnome tweaks, didn't work out so well. Thanks in advance for you answers!

UPD

here is `xinput` output

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:00 06CB:CD3E Mouse               id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ MSFT0001:00 06CB:CD3E Touchpad            id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera: Integrated C           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Ideapad extra buttons                     id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

UPD I used libinpit to make touchpad disable while typing and 'smooth touchpad gestures' and 'custom 3 finger gestures' to add gestures.
Could've made mistakes while using, I'm new to Linux

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` command.

Comment: Could you expand on “tweaks and stuff”? It will save everyone time if you share what *didn’t* work so that those suggestions are not made again (or adjusted accordingly).